# Comparing strings

Tags: bash, string

I am having trouble comparing two strings. Even though they are identical when printed, my if statement returns false.

```
#!/bin/bash

string1="HDMI"
string2="PC Speaker"

hash=$(pacmd list-sinks | grep active)
echo $hash
trigger="active port: <analog-output-speaker>"
echo $trigger

if [ "$hash" == "$trigger" ]; then
   pacmd set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo  
   echo $string1
else
   pacmd set-card-profile 0 output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo    
   echo $string2
fi
```

It produces the following output:

```
active port: <analog-output-speaker>
active port: <analog-output-speaker>
Welcome to PulseAudio! Use "help" for usage information.
>>> >>> PC Speaker
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Always quote variables**

you say `echo $hash`  but that strips leading and trailing whitespace and condenses all internal spaces. it does not show the content of the variable `$hash`

say instead `echo "<$hash>"` and you will see the leading whitespace.

It looks like pulse audio is using a tab before the word active. So put a tab at the start of the value in trigger and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

If you add `set -vx` under `#!/bin/bash` and then run your script you will see:

`[[    active port: <analog-output-speaker> == active port: <analog-output-speaker> ]]`

And you can see the strings are not the same because first string has some spaces.

for removing **whole string's spaces** you can use: `trim -d '[[:space:]]`

for removing **leading string's spaces** you can use: `sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//'`

for removing **trailing string's spaces** you can use: `sed -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//'`

Answer (score 0):

Non-printables troubling you.

Try this:

```
$ hash="   active port: <analog-output-speaker>%%%%%"   
$ echo $hash
active port: <analog-output-speaker>%%%%%
$ echo "<$hash>"
<   active port: <analog-output-speaker>%%%%%>
$ if [[ "$hash" =~ "active port" ]]; then echo matched; else echo no match; fi
matched
$ if [[ "$hash" =~ "non active port" ]]; then echo matched; else echo no match; fi
no match
```